# deserialize json string to list of wrapper

Tags: apex, json

How can i deserialize a json string into a list of wrapper in apex ? 
here is my code :

```
    public class PageLayoutErrorMsg{
      public String errorId{get;Set;}
      public String errorType{get;Set;}
      public String Message{get;Set;}       
    }
    ...
    LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg> pageErrors = new LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg>();
    pageErrors = (LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg>) JSON.deserialize(c.TECH_DisplayedErrorJSON__c,(LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg>).class);
```

I am obtaining the following syntax error : unexpected token list
Have anyone came across this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pageErrors = (List<PageLayoutErrorMsg>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(c.TECH_DisplayedErrorJSON__c);
```

OR

```
pageErrors = (List<PageLayoutErrorMsg>) JSON.deserialize(c.TECH_DisplayedErrorJSON__c,List<PageLayoutErrorMsg>.class);
```

Assuming that `c.TECH_DisplayedErrorJSON__c` has correct json.

Comment: For the list type,I should write :

LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg>.class and not (LIST<PageLayoutErrorMsg>).class